# GitError while submodule new BOX SDK

Tags: xcode, terminal, box-api

```
Vinods-Mac-mini-2:~ vinod$  cd desktop
Vinods-Mac-mini-2:desktop vinod$ git clone https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-sample-app.git
Cloning into 'box-ios-sdk-sample-app'...
remote: Counting objects: 158, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (87/87), done.
remote: Total 158 (delta 76), reused 143 (delta 63)
Receiving objects: 100% (158/158), 70.79 KiB | 83 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (76/76), done.
Vinods-Mac-mini-2:desktop vinod$ cd box-ios-sdk-sample-app
Vinods-Mac-mini-2:box-ios-sdk-sample-app vinod$ git submodule init
Submodule 'vendor/BoxSDK' (git@github.com:box/box-ios-sdk-private.git) registered for path 'vendor/BoxSDK'
Vinods-Mac-mini-2:box-ios-sdk-sample-app vinod$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'vendor/BoxSDK'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@github.com:box/box-ios-sdk-private.git' into submodule path 'vendor/BoxSDK' failed
Vinods-Mac-mini-2:box-ios-sdk-sample-app vinod$
```

This is the error i get while using terminal to integrate BOX SDK 
How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Permission denied (publickey) is actually an error you receive when you don't have a public key set up on github.  Just follow these quick steps to add them to your account: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys and everything should work.