# BOX iOS SDK SAMPLE APP: issue in cloning the folder

Tags: ios, github, box-api

I caught with the following error when i tried to clone the box sample application through terminal and here is the website where i downloaded https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-sample-app

TERMINAL ERROR:

Vinods-Mac-mini:box-ios-sdk-sample-app vinodramanathan$ git submodule update

Cloning into 'vendor/BoxSDK'...

Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of 
known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@github.com:box/box-ios-sdk-private.git' into submodule path 'vendor/BoxSDK' failed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this isn't related to the [current DDos that GitHub suffers from](https://status.github.com/messages):

> 10:20 UTC The site is unavailable as we continue mitigating a large DDoS attack.

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/16988882/2476716:

> Permission denied (publickey) is actually an error you receive when you don't have a public key set up on github. Just follow these quick steps to add them to your account: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys and everything should work.